# Where does an external process run from Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) get its memory from?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, cvs

I have a Java application running under JBoss AS 7 that is used to call a fairly complicated bash script using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`. The bash script is failing because cvs is reporting that it is running out of memory (the error was "E342: Out of memory!" to be exact).

So should I be increasing the amount of memory available to JBoss AS (with JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m" or something similar), or does this indicate that the OS itself has run out of memory?

Comment: Yes, after some Googling it would appear that vim is crashing. It's also not a case of the OS running out of memory. I upped the ram by 2 GB and watched the system stats as the error was displayed, and there is plenty of memory to go around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was vim. I was running the script that called cvs under the [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) command, which may have caused the issue. In the end I just created a script to edit the message file with a generic message:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Add a generic message
echo "Some Generic Message" > $1
# Update the time stamp. If you don't, you'll get a
# "Log message unchanged or not specified" error.
# the cvs timestamp comparison routine has a resolution
# of one second, so sleep to ensure that the timestamps
# are detected as being different.
sleep 1
touch $1
exit 0
```

Then set the EDITOR or CVSEDITOR environment variable to point to the script.

Comment: Are you doing a `cvs commit`?  If so, you could just `cvs commit -m "Message goes here."`

Comment: The cvs command is actually being run by another program I can't modify, which necessitates the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

The operating system is running out of memory.  Increasing JBoss's heap size can only make things worse.

You should be looking at things like:

- Adding more RAM.
- Increasing the amount of swap disk space.
- Cutting down on the other applications running.

Comment: Adding more memory to the system didn't make any difference. The system had at least 1GB free ram when the error was displayed. In any case, it looks like a vim problem.